# How to implement scrollbar for particular row in html

Tags: html, css

I have table with 10 row.I want vertical scrollbar for 5 row only.Can anybody tell how to add vertical scroll bar for 5 rows

```
   <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>Use this table this is fully responsive and you can adjust height of table.</p>
<style>
    .demo {
        width: 100%;
        height: 155px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    .demo table {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .demo table tr th,
    .demo table tr td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 3px 3px;
    }

    .demo table tr th {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 5px 3px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>
<div class="demo">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add a class to the particular row, for example:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr class='scroll'>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class='scroll'>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.scroll{
 overflow: auto;
 height: 200px
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if i get you very well, my first though was this:

```css
.scroll {
  height: 75;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
     <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Island Trading</td>
          <td>Helen Bennett</td>
          <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
          <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
          <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
          <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

but now i thing you want to display only 5 rows at a time, so i made this:

```css
.scroll {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps, :)